# FMTONLY vs TOP 0

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

If I needed to retrieve only metadata of a result, what is the difference between using FMTONLY  vs.  a "select top 0 ..." ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was interested in this too, after a bit of googling I found that FMTONLY is the standard vs options like Select top 0 / SELECT whatever WHERE 1=0 because as Icarus said you cant use SELECT TOP 0 for finding out what a stored proc returns.

Also when using FMTONLY Sql server wont generate / compile an execution plan since the statement isnt actually being executed.

FMTONLY is the method SSRS / Visual Studio uses when reading stored procs to get the column names.

Comment: And FMTONLY it's what Linq2SQL uses too!

Answer (score 3):

You can't use SELECT TOP 0 to find out what an stored procedure returns whereas you can use FMTONLY for that.